# Error message in self registration

Tags: community, email, error

I've set up self-registration in communities and it works fine because it registers users and assigns them to right profiles, but if the email is already in the system it gives out an apex message on the visual force page.
[image]

here are the codes that I've used for self-registration:

Visualforce component:

```html
    <apex:component controller="CommunitiesSelfRegController" id="calypso_login_form">
    <apex:form id="loginForm" forceSSL="true">
    <apex:pageMessages id="error"/>
    
        <div class="container">
        <h1 class="smalltitle"><span>Register</span></h1>
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="border-left: 0px solid">
                 <div class="panel-body">
            
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <!-- Register form -->
                <div >
                    
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form role="form">
                            <fieldset>
                           
                           
                             <div class ="col-md-6"> 
           
                       
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-4 control-label">First name</label>
                               <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
                                 <apex:inputText id="firstName" styleClass="form-control" html-placeholder="First name" value="{!firstName}"/>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                            
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Last name</label>
                               <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
                                 <apex:inputText id="lastName" styleClass="form-control" html-placeholder="Last Name" value="{!lastName}"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                
                                
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="communityusername" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Username</label>
                               <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users fa-fw"></i></span>
                                 <apex:inputText required="true" id="communityNickname" styleClass="form-control" html-placeholder="Community Username" value="{!communityNickname}"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                
                          </div> 
                          <div class ="col-md-6"> 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email</label>
                               <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o  fa-fw"></i></span>
                                 <apex:inputText id="email" styleClass="form-control" html-placeholder="Email" value="{!email}"/>
                            </div>
                          </div>      
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Password</label>
                               <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
                                 <apex:inputSecret id="password" styleClass="form-control" html-placeholder="Password" value="{!password}"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>   
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="confirmpassword" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Confirm password</label>
                               <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
                                 <apex:inputSecret id="confirmPassword" styleClass="form-control" html-placeholder="Password" value="{!confirmPassword}"/>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div> 
                                <apex:commandButton action="{!registerUser}" value="{!$Label.site.submit}" id="submit" styleClass="btn btn-default center-block center-block " />
 
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </apex:form>
    </apex:component>
```

Here is the visualforce page :

```html
    <apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" controller="CommunitiesSelfRegController" title="{!$Label.site.user_registration}" >
        <i data-category="prod-serv"></i>
        
        <apex:composition template="calypso_base">
            <apex:define name="hero-content">
                <section class="pageheader-default text-center">
                    <div class="semitransparentbg">
                        <h1 class="animated fadeInLeftBig notransition">Self Registration form</h1>
                        <h2 class="animated fadeInRightBig notransition container page-description">
                            Register to place new orders<br/>
                            and get more functionalities
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </apex:define>
            
            <apex:define name="content">
    

    <section class="container">
        <div class="row">
        

           <c:calypso_selfreg_form id="calypso_selfreg_form"/>

                    </div>
                </section>
            </apex:define>
        </apex:composition>
    </apex:page>
```

Here is the apex class:

```java
public with sharing class CommunitiesSelfRegController {
    
    public String firstName {get; set;}
    public String lastName {get; set;}
    public String email {get; set;}
    public String password {get; set {password = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String confirmPassword {get; set { confirmPassword = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String communityNickname {get; set { communityNickname = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    
    public CommunitiesSelfRegController() {}
    
   

     private boolean isValidPassword() {
            return password == confirmPassword;
        }
        public PageReference registerUser() {
        
               // it's okay if password is null - we'll send the user a random password in that case
            if (!isValidPassword()) {
                ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, Label.site.passwords_dont_match);
                ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
                return null;
            }    
    
            String profileId = null; // To be filled in by customer.
            String roleEnum = null; // To be filled in by customer.
            String accountId = ''; // To be filled in by customer.
            
            String userName = email;
    
            User u = new User();
            u.Username = userName;
            u.Email = email;
            u.FirstName = firstName;
            u.LastName = lastName;
            u.CommunityNickname = communityNickname;
            u.ProfileId = profileId;
            
            String userId = Site.createPortalUser(u, accountId, password);
          
            if (userId != null) { 
                if (password != null && password.length() > 1) {
                    return Site.login(userName, password, null);
                }
                else {
                    PageReference page = System.Page.CommunitiesSelfRegConfirm;
                    page.setRedirect(true);
                    return page;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I was looking all over and I couldn't find the message in the system that says, contact your administrator, I want to change it something such as: your email is already in the system please go here :" or "Please contact something@sometihng.com"

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Seems this error message thrown by the system itself.

Below are a few common reasons why you may be encountering the problem:

**The community is not published.** In case you're working with a community that is offline or in Preview status, you need to publish the community before self-registration will work.
**The Account Owner does not have a User Role assigned.** If you're creating a new Account record on the fly, especially in B2C situations, you need to make sure you assign a default account owner that also has a User Role value. Any role will do, and you can use either a workflow rule or Apex to perform the assignment.
**The site guest user does not have Create and Read permissions on the Account and Contact objects.** Edit Public Access Settings for the community's Force.com site to grant these permissions, along with field permissions for any fields that are included on the self-registration form. Note that by default the site's profile will not have these permissions.
**Self-registration is not enabled for the community.** Go to Manage Communities, click Edit and make sure the Login settings show that self-registration is enabled.